# Error From Extracting Int from String Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, replaceall

I keep getting an "invalid int" error in logcat, how do I correct this?

```
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           digits.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
           String[] guessArray = digits.split("");
           int[] guessInt = new int[6];
           for(i=0;i<5;i++){
               guessInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(guessArray[i]);
               if(guessInt[i] == actualInt[i]){
                   correct++;
               }
               else{
                   easyGuessDisplay.setText("Sorry! Try again!");
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   });
```

in this case `digits` is a String I split into an array and then the value of each index is compared to a previously stored array. I get a crash and logcat yells at me:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
            at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
```

I want to extract all the integers from `digits` and store them in a new array for comparison.

Comment: Please refrain from using images to show your errors.

Comment: How else would I show my logcat comment then?

Comment: @gamerguy0102 your replaceAll method  isn't returning a String which is formatted correctly to be parsed to an Integer.

Comment: @gamerguy0102, you should copy and paste the text into the question. If that doesn't work, you should strongly consider re-typing it. It makes it easier for everyone to see/read as well as helping the indexing and searching of text in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Made the edit for the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable and hence not modified in place.

You need

```
digits = digits.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

Also, `split("")` will return leading **empty** string before Java 8. You need to account for that too.

Probably do,

```
guessInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(guessArray[i + 1]);
```

Comment: The leading whitespace is what was throwing it off. Using the `i+1` index helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Codebender is correct. Besides that, place Integer.parseInt(guessArray[i]); inside trycatch block to catch any invalid number exception and deal with it.